# Conditional Formatting (duplicate values) (partial)

Tags: excel

Right now I use Conditional Formatting -> Highlight Cells Rules -> Duplicate Values and it generates this

```
Example1
A1 = bear
B1 = bear
Result = marked as duplicated

Example2
A1 = HoRsE
B1 = horse
Result = marked as duplicated

Example3
A1 = bear
B1 = a dog and a bear was walking
Result = not marked as duplicated
```

How can I make that Example3 is also marked as duplicated since it contains the string in A1 (has to be full string of A1)

> A1 and B1 are only examples, my wishes is that it would be possible to
> mark the whole excel content and check for duplicates alike the
> built-in standard but with the additional setting of checking for
> partial results in the B section

Comment: How do you see this in practice? If cell `A1` contains "horse" and `Z213` contains "seahorse", what are your expectations? Would both cells show the special formatting?

Comment: Good question, I forgot to mention it. Yes the expectation would be that both would be marked. As well as if A1 is contained in B100, B101, B102 and so on, ALL should be marked. So the A column is the main column to extract string from to match any of column B if contained string of A. But it should not check other columns or mark other columns except A and B.